# API for uploading image is not working

Tags: php, android, image, api

I have created an API so android application can connect to the website the problem I am facing is I am unable to provide access to provide API to upload image to the server as of now I have created so image would be saving as base64 code but the main problem is that when every API call is made and image uploading it is giving me an error of image not found unable to load file stream. Here is the error I am Getting

```
<b>Warning</b>: fopen(uploads/testimg.png): failed to open stream: No such 

file or directory in <b>/home/begazed/public_html/api/classfiles/Photo.php</b> on line <b>87</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>/home/begazed/public_html/api/classfiles/Photo.php</b> on line <b>88</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>/home/begazed/public_html/api/classfiles/Photo.php</b> on line <b>89</b><br />
{"result":1,"message":"Image upload complete, Please check your php file directory"}
```

This is the function I have created to upload image to the server

```
function upload_photo($connect, $base, $filename) {     
        $binary   = base64_decode($base);

        $query = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO test_photo (filename) VALUES (:filename)");
        $query->execute(array(':filename' => $filename));

        header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');

        $file = fopen('uploads/'.$filename, 'wb');
        fwrite($file, $binary);
        fclose($file);
        $err['result']  = 1;
        $err['message'] = 'Image upload complete, Please check your php file directory';
        return json_encode($err);
    }
```

The main api file from where the request is handled

```
    switch($action)
  {
  case 'upload_photo':
    $base     = $_REQUEST['image'];
    $filename = $_REQUEST['filename'];

    echo $retval = $photo->upload_photo($connect, $base, $filename);
break;

default:
    echo "Invalid Request";
break;
```

}

tthis is the url used to make a call

www.domainname.com/api/api.php?action=upload_photo&fimename=(filename)&image=iamge nae

Can anyone help me out to fix this error

Comment: There is no one to help me out :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your PHP-file is included from another file, located somewhere else, then the code will use *that* file path as basis.

Include basically "copys" the content of the included file into into your script, which makes the paths relative from the parent script, not the script that's included.

To fix this, you can use the magic constant `__DIR__`, which returns the absolute path to the file itself.

So changing:

```
fopen('uploads/' . $filename, 'wb')
```

to

```
fopen(__DIR__ . '/uploads/' . $filename, 'wb')
```

should solve your issue.